Blocking [IPaddress:8080] on nginx
I have an app working on port 8080 perfectly with the domain desh.onecloudhelper.com and now when I hit the Public IP address of the Server, I can still view the same app running using the server's public IP address.
What I am trying to achieve is that If someone uses the [IPaddress:8080] to access the site, that request should be blocked but when someone accesses the site using the [domainname:8080], that request should not be blocked through the browser.
This is the config file that I am using:
server {
listen 80;
server_name desh.onecloudhelper.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}


Instead of blocking it just redirect it. Blocking it doesn’t provide any security if that’s why you want to block it

@FrankThomas you can't block the HTTP/TCP connection but you can block the request(s). Create a second server block with listen 80 default_server (no server_name needed) which responds to all requests with an error code like 401 or 500, or if you prefer, nginx's return 444 which closes the connection with no HTTP response at all. Crossdupe https://serverfault.com/questions/1108830/using-nginx-to-block-connections-that-arent-addressed-to-my-domain .
